# mvc - show/hide stuff based on what view it is for a user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-3.5

Im using asp.net mvc. I have a create and edit form which are very similar so im using a user control for the form.
and placing that in each view.

the form is very slightly different on the edit form eg it has some extra text and a link.

how can i show/hide that based on the view im in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either put it in the model (i.e. an "IsEditMode" or "IsAddMode" parameter) or, better yet, pass it in via the ViewData:

```
<%
ViewData["IsEditMode"] = true;
Html.RenderPartial("FormView", Model);
%>
```

Then just check for the IsEditMode value in the ViewData

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebForms style control (`<asp:label>`), you can create a `bool` property on the control and trigger the visibility of the fragment based on that property.

If you are using the MVC style control (`Html.RenderPartial()`), you can pass the `bool` value in the control model. If your control does not take currently a model, your `bool` value will become your model.